# How do I prevent PysimpleGUI from closing the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

For some reason, even though I'm not sure why it's doing that, my program just closes the window instead of it doing what I want it to do

```
   while True:
     event, values = main_window.read()
     if event in (None,"Exit"):
         break
     if event == 'GPU info':
         print('cool')
     main_window.close()
```

Any clues to how I change its behaviour to hide or do nothing when I press a button that is not exit?

Comment: Please update your question with the correct indentation from your actual code.

Comment: Done. Don't know why it didn't do it the first time

Comment: Now it looks like ‘main_window.close()’ is inside your loop. Did you mean to unindent just that line?

Comment: Oh my god. I'm so stupid. I literally spent the last hour on this and i had no idea why.
I'm new to Python's indentation oriented reading and this is one hard lesson learned

Comment: You're NOT stupid.  I've spent much more than an hour due to a bad ";" in a C program.  You're human and a programmer... welcome to the club 

Answer (score 1):

main_window.close() is in the while loop.

Comment: I think you should make your explanation of how this causes the problem and how to fix it more obvious.

Comment: Explanation - how this causes the problem: `close` closes the window INSIDE the while loop.  The obvious fix: Move it out of the while loop.